# How to perform SFTP to a remote server using airflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, sftp, google-cloud-networking

We have a scenario where we need to copy a file from GCS (google cloud storage) to a remote SFTP server via airflow without using any intermediate on-premise Unix server.

Is there any way to achieve this task with/without using GCP Compute Service or using docker POD via airflow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`GCSToSFTPOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/bf727525e1fd777e51cc8bc17285f6093277fdef/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_sftp.py#L34):

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.transfers.gcs_to_sftp import GCSToSFTPOperator

copy_file_from_gcs_to_sftp = GCSToSFTPOperator(
    task_id="file-copy-gsc-to-sftp",
    sftp_conn_id=SFTP_CONN_ID,
    source_bucket=os.environ.get("GCP_GCS_BUCKET_1_SRC", "test-gcs-sftp"),
    source_object="file.csv",
    destination_path="/tmp/single-file/",
)
```

The operator downloads the file to temp dir on the Airflow worker and upload it to the SFTP server.
You can read more about the operator in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/transfer/gcs_to_sftp.html#google-cloud-storage-transfer-operator-to-sftp).

Comment: What is meant by SFTP_CONN_ID? Is it a connection string such as "sftp://user:password@localhost:22"?

Comment: @alex-mount no, its the connection name as defined in Airflow Connection. See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html

Comment: Clear, thanks. I'm usign the opposite operator (SFTPToGCSOperator) but i'm getting this error: "socket.timeout: timed out". What could be the main causes?